# Mail not send when using Laravel Jobs

Tags: laravel, email, queue, jobs

I am sending two mails after payment is successfully done, so it is taking too much time I try to used Laravel mail queue but one mail is sending fine the other just not.

This is my code.

```
//controller
public function saveData(Request $request){
   SendEmailJob::dispatch($mailBody, 0, $request->email);
}

//mail
public function build()
{
        if ($this->val == 0){
            return $this->view('mail.orderMail')->with(['message' => $this])->subject($this->mailBody['subject']);
        }
        elseif ($this->val == 1){
            return $this->view('mail.mailSale')->with(['message' => $this])->subject($this->mailBody['subject']);
        }
 }

//job
public function handle()
    {
        //dd(config('queue.default'));
        if ($this->val == 0){
        Mail::to($this->email)->send( new orderMail( $this->mailBody, 0) );
    }
    elseif ($val == 1){
        Mail::to($this->email)->send( new orderMail( $this->mailBody, 1) );
    }
    }
```

Kindly help.

Comment: `if ($this->val == 0)`

`elseif ($val == 1)`

You check val in 2 different ways, are you sure they are the same variable? Which is the mail that isn't dispatched? Is $val declared somewhere?

Comment: no and all the values are correct I check all 3 parameters in every file

Comment: Which is the mail that doesn't start?

Comment: Anyway, inside `handle()` function, try changing `elseif ($val == 1){` to `elseif ($this->val == 1){`, just to be sure

Comment: both procces starts and complts but the mail i need to sned to the user is not sending but the mail i am sending to the server is working fine

Comment: i am running it form htdocs folder like http://localhost/ga/ so if I start the server with php artisan serve will it change

Comment: If i get what you are saying and you are correct the problem could be in the mailing server or in the building of the mail. Did you try to check laravel logs for any exceptions?

Comment: yes no errors and one more thing if send mail directly from the controller it works just fine

Comment: Can you paste the piece of code where you declare $val?

Comment: //controller
public function saveData(Request $request){
   SendEmailJob::dispatch($mailBody, 0, $request->email);
}
this my controller where i dispatch

Comment: I meant where you `$val=...` the first time, it could be that you forgot the `this->` between `$` and `val`

Comment: You can also try calling your job by: `Artisan::queue('name:of_the_job');` in the controller. This should automatically queue your job execution

Comment: the queue is working fine without any error and no i dont miss any $ sign for declaring the variable mail it self working but when job runs it dont send one mail from two one is also working fine

Comment: The problem is that unless you declared `$val = $this->val` inside handle() the second condition can't trigger as `$val` has no value. I also don't get if the handle piece is supposed to send 2 mails or not, because the code says "send one OR the other"

Comment: ok so what your saying is if send only one mail from handle function it will work
i will try

Comment: no wont work I thing the problem is not in mail sending but gmail or other mail services is not accepting this mail but I dont know why and how to find out

Comment: I was saying that using an if - elseif statement allows you to send only one of the two. Moreover if one of the variables you check is not defined the program will never execute that code. I'll try to post an answer with some code, i hope it can get you somewhere. If the problem is gmail servers there is really little we can do apart from changing server or checking spam folders

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give an answer with the info I got inside comments.

You should have a command class with the following structure

```
class class_name extends command {

protected $signature = 'name:of_your_command';
$val=something     

public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

public function handle()
    {
        //yourcode
    }
}
```

Anything that is not declared inside handle has to be called with `$this->`

Let's now analyze your handle function:

```
public function handle()
    {
        //dd(config('queue.default'));
        if ($this->val == 0){
        Mail::to($this->email)->send( new orderMail( $this->mailBody, 0) );
    }
    elseif ($val == 1){
        Mail::to($this->email)->send( new orderMail( $this->mailBody, 1) );
    }
}
```

As you can see there is an `if - elseif` statement. This means that depending on `$this->val` value either one mail will be sent or the other.
To send them both you should have something like this:

```
public function handle()
    {
        Mail::to($this->email)->send( new orderMail( $this->mailBody, 0) );
        Mail::to($this->email)->send( new orderMail( $this->mailBody, 1) );
    }
}
```

If you want to send one or the other depending on `$this->val`'s value you can use just one call by adding the value to the function call instead of hard coding it:

```
Mail::to($this->email)->send( new orderMail( $this->mailBody, $this->val) );
```

The thing that puzzled me with your code was that the `elseif` condition is checked with `$val` instead of `$this->val` as all other checks are made.
The problem with this is that if you didn't declare `handle()` like this

```
public function handle()
    {
        $val = $this->val;
        //yourcode
    }
```

`$val` will have no value at all, as every class parameter has to be called with `$this->`. This means that when the code runs it goes like this:

```
// First possibility
// starting variables
$this->val = 1

// code process
1. Is $this->val equal to 0? So, is 1 equal to 0? no
2. Then, is $val equal to 1? So, is undefined equal to 1? no
3. No mail sent

///////////////////////

// Second possibility
// starting variables
$this->val = 0

// code process
1. Is $this->val equal to 0? So, is 0 equal to 0? yes, send mail
2. The previous check was successful, no need to continue
3. Second mail is not sent
```

Hope this helps you at least a little bit

Comment: as i said i am sending two mails from controller it is taking to much time so i was trying to send the mails through the job as a separate process so if send one mail with all values given hardcoded it still dont send the mail out side the mail server